# DataBrew Not Working on Buckets in us-west-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I want to use DataBrew to normalize the data that is dropped into S3 buckets each month. DataBrew is not available in us-west-1 (my preferred region) so I am working with DataBrew in us-west-2.

However, all the buckets that data is being dropped into are in the us-west-1 region. When I try to access those S3 buckets from DataBrew, I get the error message "The bucket xxxxxx was found in us-west-1 instead of us-west-2. Select a bucket that was created in us-west-2."

Is there no way for DataBrew to connect to buckets in a different region?

If not, is the best way to overcome this hurdle to take advantage of S3's [cross region replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html)?

Answer (score 1):

DataBrew is available in `us-west-1` region and you should be able to use all features in the region.

Please make sure to select "US West (N. California)" region from the drop down on the AWS console, or simply use this link: https://us-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/databrew/home?region=us-west-1#landing after you log in.

[image]